# How to get minutes interval from created datetime in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to count data between created datatime interval.

I have tried below code

```
$check->where( function( $exp, $q ) {
                    return $exp->between(
                        $q->newExpr( 'NOW()' ),
                        $q->newExpr( 'created' ),
                        $q->newExpr( 'DATE_ADD( created, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE )' )
                    );
 } );
```

I have also tried

```
$check->where( [
             'TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, created, NOW() ) >=' => 1,
             'TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, created, NOW() ) <=' => 30,
] );
```

Both time I am getting result `0`

but if I try with the debug.log query I am getting result `1`

```
SELECT (COUNT(*)) AS count FROM money_transfer_transactions MoneyTransferTransactions WHERE (user_id = 2 AND receiver_account_number = '01737810405' AND NOW() BETWEEN created AND DATE_ADD( created, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE ))
```

Here correct ans is 1.

How I will get 30 min between two datetime interval ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chronos](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html) class to deal with dates in CakePHP. You can [create](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html#creating-instances) instances and then [diff](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html#generating-differences) them.